# HtmlAgilityPack : illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm getting an "illegal characters in path" error in this code. I've mentioned "Error Occuring Here" as a comment in the line where the error is occuring.

```
var document = htmlWeb.Load(searchUrl);
var hotels = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
             .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
             x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("listing-content"));

int count = 1;
foreach (var hotel in hotels)
{
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    htmlDoc.Load(hotel.InnerText);      // Error Occuring Here //
    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        var hotelName = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='business-container-inner']//div[@class='business-content clearfix']//div[@class='business-name-wrapper']//h3[@class='business-name fn org']//div[@class='srp-business-name']//a[0]");
        foreach (var name in hotelName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should use `LoadHtml` method with loads a string. `Load` method loads from *file*

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(hotel.InnerText);
```

Comment: Thak you LB. This worked. I didn't noticed that tiny mistake. Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 5):

This simply means you're trying to load a file with an [invalid character in the file path/name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The error is here:

```
htmlDoc.Load(hotel.InnerText);
```

..because that overload expects the path to the file:

```
public void Load(string path)
```

Use `LoadHtml` to load a HTML fragment:

```
public void LoadHtml(string html)
```